# Is my SSD overprovisioning enabled?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

In Samsung Magician software, for an EVO 850:

[image]

On the one hand, the unpartitioned space says "OP", but on the other hand, the "Set OP" button is grayed out, and it says "OP can be set or cleared only for the last accessible partition", and I'm not sure what that even means.

Comment: That looks very different from how my drive looks - its not showing the OP space at all. What's Q: contain? My guess is you can't *alter* the overprovisioned space - but its set already.

Comment: The first and last partitions are system stuff, Lenovo recovery partition.  I created the empty chunk in GParted